# Electromagnetic fields in voltage biased conducting strip

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, computational-physics, maxwell-equations, conductors

Consider a conducting rectangular strip of length $L$ (along x-axis) and width $W$ (along y-axis), with a potential difference (rather EMF $\int E.dx$) V(t) applied. We can assume that V(t) changes sufficiently slowly to treat the problem ``adiabatically". That is, I am hoping we can solve the static problem for a constant voltage and smoothly interpolate the fields.

The current can be numerically calculated as $j(V,\vec{A})$, depending on both the scalar and vector potentials. Similarly, we can calculate the charge density numerically $\rho(V,A)$. In the adiabatic/static approximation mentioned above, I guess we can assume $\partial\rho/\partial t=0$.

How does one formulate the problem to numerically solve for the fields and potentials in this strip from Maxwell's equations?